# Overloaded function from base class never being called although required

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading

I'm trying to write a container that takes both int and int&.
Doing it in one class works:

```
template <class T>
class unified_class
{
public:
    virtual void f(T &i){}
    virtual void f(T &&i) {}
};
```

calling:

```
unified_class<int> u;
u.f(8); // going to the second method
int a = 9;
u.f(a); // going to the first method
```

but when I'm trying to split it between two classes, something weird is going on:

```
template <class T>
class base_class
{
public:
    virtual void f(T &&i) { /* it never reaches here*/}
};

template <class T>
class derived_class : public base_class<T>
{
public:
    using base_class<T>::f;
    virtual void f(T &i){}
};
```

Calling the same function calls from before, results in calling derived class's f() in both cases.

Do I miss something?

Comment: what compiler do you use? I compile fine with gcc 4.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the problem with g++ 4.6.3.  This is the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;

template <class T>
class base_class
{
public:
    virtual void f(T &&i) { cerr << "base_class\n"; }
};

template <class T>
class derived_class : public base_class<T>
{
public:
    using base_class<T>::f;
    virtual void f(T &i) { cerr << "derived_class\n";  }
};

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  derived_class<int> u;
  u.f(8); // going to the second method
  int a = 9;
  u.f(a); // going to the first method
}
```

and I got this result:

```
base_class
derived_class
```

Comment: Running your code with Visual Studio, I get:
    derived_class
    derived_class

Answer (score 1):

If you're really seeing the result you say you are with the code you've posted then this is definitely a compiler bug.  You should not be able to call f(T&) with a constant when T is "int".  Even if there were some sort of hiding going on, and I think the using takes care of that, the program should utterly fail to compile rather than call the wrong function.

Answer (score 1):

You'r using Visual Studio 2010 which provides this feature as extension that temporary binds to the *non-const* reference. That is why it is calling `T&` version in both cases. This *compiler-extension*, if at all it is, should rather be called *compiler bug*, because it *replaces* the behaviour defined by the Standard.

However, in Standard C++, the temporary object created out of the integral literal `8` must not bind to the *non-const* reference, and therefore the call must resolve to the function which takes `T&&` as argument.